# Inconsistent results trying to parse og:image tag from a webpage manually and programmatically

Tags: html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I first manually browse to the below URL:

[Mounting injuries won't stop Germany's path to World Cup](http://sports.yahoo.com/news/mounting-injuries-wont-stop-germanys-path-world-cup-122032650--sow.html)

Then if view the page source and look for og:image meta tags I find the following:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://l.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/JjwtkhIEdT9nKxLp8p0LFQ--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7cT04NTt3PTYwMA--/http://media.zenfs.com/en_us/News/Reuters/2013-10-08T122032Z_1_CBRE9970YAZ00_RTROPTP_2_SOCCER-WORLD.JPG"/>
```

However, if I try to parse the same url programmatically, I get a generic Yahoo stock icon. Here is the code that I am using:

```
string url = "http://sports.yahoo.com/news/mounting-injuries-wont-stop-germanys-path-world-cup-122032650--sow.html";

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
string newsPageSource = wc.DownloadString(sourceUri.ToString());
doc.LoadHtml(newsPageSource);
...
```

(I have removed the rest fro brevity).

If I debug here and inspect the **newsPageSource** string that contains the content of the target web page and look for og:image tag, its contents are different:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://l.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/81I5U991YW6EEaB2Cjd58g--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7cT04NTt3PTYwMA--/http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/social/images/social_default_logo-1481777.png"/>
```

So not sure what is going on here. I guess, when browsing manually, the original URL is probably redirecting to some other internal URL but when doing this programmatically, the code just grabs the first "snapshot" of page source, without waiting a bit longer and executing any redirects. Can anyone shed light here? Or better yet, how would I extract the real image (2013-10-08T122032Z_1_CBRE9970YAZ00_RTROPTP_2_SOCCER-WORLD.JPG) in this case instead of getting a Yahoo stock icon (social_default_logo-1481777.png).

Somehow Facebook and Google+ are smart enough to extract the correct image when I paste the same link.

Thanks,
Archil

Comment: I also have l.yimg.com urls when I do view source in my Chrome browser. That being said, yahoo can use tons of tricks so you don't scrape their site easily (user-agent, javascript, etc.). Standard HTTP redirects should be natively supported by the WebClient.

Comment: Thanks Simon. I used your suggestion and played with the user-agent string. Basically if I set it to a similar string that my browser would normally use then I do get the correct image. I guess Yahoo checks the user-agent in a request header and if it is blank then it just serves stock images.